# Compass compiler errors out every other time

Tags: compass-sass, sass

I have a Grunt task for compiling scss files using Compass and build fails every other time. When I change a file that uses a Compass mixin, e.g. `@import box-sizing(border-box)`, it fails and says that plugin is not included (it actually is included in a file "all.scss" using `@import "compass/css3/box-sizing"`, and then it includes other scss files.

Second time (after you see the error) you try to compile it, it works just fine. I guess the reason is that if other files (specifically my "all.scss" file) has not been changed, it skips it during compilation, so include is not found.

Also, if I use `require 'box-sizing'` or `require "compass/css3/box-sizing"` in config.rb, it also fails saying that it can't find this plugin.

Any idea what's the cause?

Comment: `box-sizing` isn't a plugin or extension, it is simply a stylesheet that is part of the Compass library.  That's why you can't reference it in `config.rb`.  Extensions are things like (Sassy Buttons)[http://jaredhardy.com/sassy-buttons/] or (Suzy)[https://github.com/ericam/susy/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-sizing` is a [mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_sizing/#mixin-box-sizing), so you want to `@include` it, not `@import`:

```
@include box-sizing(border-box);
```

As you were importing it, the compiler treats it as a Compass extension, which is missing in the `config.rb`. But it's not an extension in the first place, it's part of Compass in the first place!

So changing `@import` to `@include` will solve your issue.

See http://sass-lang.com/#mixins for syntax.